# compiling php 5.6 with ldap error

Tags: php, ldap, build-process

**SYSTEM:** 
php 5.6.4
centos 7.1.503 (Core)

I get the following error when compiling php:

```
configure: error: Don't know how to define struct flock on this system, set --enable-opcache=no
```

I got that with following compile args:

```
sudo ./configure --with-apxs2 --disable-cgi --enable-sockets --enable-pcntl --with-readline --with-zlib --with-openssl --with-curl  --enable-mbstring --with-gettext --enable-soap --enable-wddx --with-tidy --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-gd --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-freetype-dir --with-libxml-dir --with-xmlrpc --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-config-file-path=/etc/httpd/conf --with-mcrypt --enable-opcache --with-ldap --prefix=/usr/local/php-5.6.4
```

I dont think its opcache related, as if i remove the --with-ldap flag it compiles fine. Also 5.5 is already compiled and running w/ ldap just fine. This upgrade to 5.6 is choking however w/ that flag set.

also in config.log, this seems like it could be relevant:

```
configure:66022: result: no
configure:66025: checking for mmap() using regular file shared memory support
configure:66097: cc -o conftest -I/usr/include -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden  -L/usr/lib  conftest.c -lmcrypt -lltdl -lldap -lpng -lz -ljpeg -lcurl -lz -lrt -lm -ldl -lnsl  -lxml2 -lz -lm -ldl -lssl -lcrypto -lcurl -lxml2 -lz -lm -ldl -lfreetype >&5
configure:66097: $? = 0
configure:66097: ./conftest
./configure: line 2331: 29392 Aborted                 (core dumped)     ./conftest$ac_exeext
configure:66097: $? = 134
configure: program exited with status 134
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
```

Comment: What happens when you set the requested --with-opcache=no? Does it compile then?

Comment: SOLVED: changed --with-ldap to --with-ldap=shared